# Cannot load Assembly while installing package in uipath

Tags: entity-framework-core, uipath, uipath-activity

I've created a custom activity in Visual studio using UiPath Activity Creator. In this activity I'm working with Entity Framework core and connecting with database. I published my project successfully and when I try to install this package in UiPath It says following package cannot be installed and showed following error in logs:

**Cannot load assembly: C:\Users\maryum.siddique.nuget\packages\MyActivity.Test.activities/0.1.0.629111039\lib/net461/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll : System.TypeLoadException: Method 'DisposeAsync' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.**

I have no idea what's the issue. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same error.
If you are making this library in visual studio, make sure that the library is a `.net framework` project, NOT a `.net core` project.

From my experience UiPath does not like `.net core`.

I'm not sure why, but it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced this error. It is due to the wrong library being selected when you created your project.

In order to fix it make sure you follow the steps:

1. Create a new project on Visual Studio
2. Select C# from the language drop-down
3. Select Library from the project type drop-down
4. Choose - Class Library (.NET Framework)

However I suggest you make use of the UI path create activity extension to make a UiPath Standard Activity Project.